# facebook data doesn't match (excel and FQL)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Building a facebook analytics application. I'm fetching the daily new likes as followed:

```
 $start_time = $timestamp = strtotime('2012-01-30');
 $end_time = $timestamp = strtotime('2012-02-27');
 $fanadds = $facebook->api('/**************/insights/page_fan_adds?since='.$start_time.'&until='.$end_time);
```

When i compare these results with the data from an exported Excel sheet, the numbers don't match.

Comparison:
[link to comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lkYe.png)
[image]

Does anyone has an idea why this is?

Comment: Are you querying the in the same timezone that the frontend is using?
Facebook stores everything in PST/PDT, so you may need to manually offset when querying the API

Comment: That doesn't change the values, it only changes the day that he begins fetching values, a day later. 
added date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
image of compare:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/m05iw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just seen https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204643062967390, one of the comments there suggests that page_fan_adds can count the same user multiple times if they like, unlike and like again

This sounds like it might be the cause - the [Insights documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) does list page_fan_adds and page_fan_adds_unique separately; implying page_fan_adds will have duplicates

Comment: This resolved it, added unique parameter. With the combination of changing timezone to date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); Thanks!